# How to position multiple divs in different location inside div using flex direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

i am trying to achieve attached similar design[image: Design Image]

but unable to do so,
i am using css flex direction and wish to achieve it that way only..how can i do this?
in my css section i have also tried and commented code that i was using but failed every time..if flex direction doesn't work,is there any other way i can acheiev this?

below is my html code and css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/test.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        
    <div id="div1">


        <table class="table-content" class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-sm w-auto text-xsmall">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>
                                Builder Call
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Number
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Date
                            </th>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="builder" id={{ID}}+"builder" class="lopem">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                        <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id={{ID}}+"number">

                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" id={{ID}}+"calldate">
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>
                                Broker Call
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Number
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Date
                            </th>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="broker" id={{ID}}+"broker" class="lopem">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                        <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id={{ID}}+"brokernumber">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" id={{ID}}+"brokerdate">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </Table>
    </div>
    {{!-- second table --}}
    <div id="div2">
        <table class="table-content">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Slot Enquiry
                </th>
                <th>
                    Slot type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Slot Enquiry Date
                </th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slot" id={{ID}}+"slot" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Done">Done</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                            <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                            <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                            <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slottype" id={{ID}}+"slottype" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Builder">Builder</option>
                            <option value="Broker">Brokder</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" value='' id={{ID}}+"enquirydate">
                    </td>


                </tr>

            </tbody>



        </Table>
    </div>

    {{!-- third div  --}}

    <div id="div3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            Email Builder
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email Address
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select name="emailbuilder" id={{ID}}+"emailbuilder" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="" id={{ID}}+"emailaddress">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            Email Broker
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email Address
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="emailbroker" id={{ID}}+"emailbroker" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="" id={{ID}}+"brokeraddress">
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="div4">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            WhatsApp Builder
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="whatsappbuilder" id={{ID}}+"whatsappbuilder" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            WhatsApp Broker
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="whatsappbroker" id={{ID}}+"whatsappbroker" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="div5">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Online Research
                </th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <select name="onlineresearch" id={{ID}}+"onlineresearch" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Done">Done</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                            <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                            <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                            <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

css Code: i have commented my css push and try code but failed:

```
/* .table-content{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 42px;
    
}
.table-content tr td{
    
    padding-top: 10px;
} */
/* #div1{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;

}
#div2{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 36px;
    width: 443px;
    
}
#div3{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 36px;
    /* float: right; */
    /* direction: rtl; */
    /* text-align: center; */
/* } */

div{
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid;
    
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap those divs inside a container and attach your flex css to the container as similar to the snippet below. you can put your tables inside those box

```css
.container {
   width: 960px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}


.box1 {
   background: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
}

.box2 {
   background: blue;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
}

.box3 {
   background: green;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"> </div>
  <div class="box2"> </div>
  <div class="box3"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little refactoring your code of `html` and deploying a new `CSS`, desired output as per the image provided is achieved herewith. Please check if this is something you were looking for. **For better verification please view the output in full page mode.**

```css
.row-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
input, select{
border: none;
}
table{
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tbody tr{
border: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
}
table tbody td{
border: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
}
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 12px;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/test.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div id="div1">


        
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>
                                Builder Call
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Number
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Date
                            </th>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="builder" id={{ID}}+"builder" class="lopem">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                        <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id={{ID}}+"number">

                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" id={{ID}}+"calldate">
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
              

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>
                                Broker Call
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Number
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Calling Date
                            </th>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="broker" id={{ID}}+"broker" class="lopem">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                        <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                        <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id={{ID}}+"brokernumber">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" id={{ID}}+"brokerdate">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
             

       
    </div>
       <div id="div3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            Email Builder
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email Address
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select name="emailbuilder" id={{ID}}+"emailbuilder" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="" id={{ID}}+"emailaddress">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            Email Broker
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email Address
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="emailbroker" id={{ID}}+"emailbroker" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="" id={{ID}}+"brokeraddress">
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
      <div id="div4">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            WhatsApp Builder
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="whatsappbuilder" id={{ID}}+"whatsappbuilder" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            WhatsApp Broker
                        </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <select name="whatsappbroker" id={{ID}}+"whatsappbroker" class="lopem">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                                    <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row-wrapper">
    <!-- second table -->
    <div id="div2">
        <table class="table-content">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Slot Enquiry
                </th>
                <th>
                    Slot type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Slot Enquiry Date
                </th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slot" id={{ID}}+"slot" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Done">Done</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                            <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                            <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                            <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slottype" id={{ID}}+"slottype" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Builder">Builder</option>
                            <option value="Broker">Brokder</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" value='' id={{ID}}+"enquirydate">
                    </td>


                </tr>

            </tbody>



        </Table>
    </div>

    <!-- third div  -->

    

    

    <div id="div5">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Online Research
                </th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <select name="onlineresearch" id={{ID}}+"onlineresearch" class="lopem">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Done">Done</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                            <option value="Not_Required">Not Required</option>
                            <option value="No_answer">No Answer</option>
                            <option value="Not_Connected">Not Connected</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to achieve your goal.

**Variant 1**
Use one container which contains all your divs, use `display: flex` and set it to wrap when the row width is exceeded (`flex-wrap: wrap`) and finally set the desired widths for the child-divs.

**Variant 2** Use a main-container which contains another div for each column, set the main-container to `display: flex` and adjust the width of the column-containers as needed.

```css
/* VARIANT 1 */
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* set widths of the divs according to your needs */
#div1,
#div4 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

#div2,
#div5 {
  flex: 1;
  /* stretch to fill remaining space */
}

#div3,
#div6 {
  width: 50px;
  /* fixed width */
}

/* VARIANT 2 */

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

/* set widths of the sub containers according to your needs */
.container2>.subcontainer:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 3;
}

.container2>.subcontainer:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}

.container2>.subcontainer:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}

/* below styles for demo only */
#div,
#div1,
#div2,
#div3,
#div4,
#div5,
#div6 {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
      V1

    <div class="container1">
      <div id="div1">Table 1</div>
      <div id="div2">Table 2</div>
      <div id="div3">Table 3</div>
      <div id="div4">Table 4</div>
      <div id="div5">Table 5</div>
      <div id="div6">Table 6</div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    V2
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="subcontainer">
        <div id="div">Table 1</div>
        <div id="div">Table 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="subcontainer">
        <div id="div">Table 3</div>
        <div id="div">Table 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="subcontainer">
        <div id="div">Table 5</div>
        <div id="div">Table 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```